# Analyzing assembly code

Tags: c, assembly

```
 $ gcc -O2 -S test.c -----------------------(1)
      .file "test.c"
    .globl accum
       .bss
       .align 4
       .type accum, @object
       .size accum, 4
    accum:
       .zero 4
       .text
       .p2align 2,,3
    .globl sum
       .type sum, @function
    sum:
       pushl %ebp
       movl  %esp, %ebp
       movl  12(%ebp), %eax
       addl  8(%ebp), %eax
       addl  %eax, accum
       leave
       ret
       .size sum, .-sum
       .p2align 2,,3
    .globl main
       .type main, @function
    main:
       pushl %ebp
       movl  %esp, %ebp
       subl  $8, %esp
       andl  $-16, %esp
       subl  $16, %esp
       pushl $11
       pushl $10
       call  sum
       xorl  %eax, %eax
       leave
       ret
       .size main, .-main
       .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
       .ident   "GCC: (GNU) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-9)"
```

This is an assembly code generated from this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int accum = 0;

int sum(int x,int y)
{
   int t = x+y;
   accum +=t;
   return t;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   int i = 0,x=10,y=11;
   i = sum(x,y);
   return 0;
}
```

Also, this is the object code generated from the above program:

```
$objdump -d test.o -------------------------(2) 

test.o:     file format elf32-i386

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <sum>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   6:   03 45 08                add    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   9:   01 05 00 00 00 00       add    %eax,0x0
   f:   c9                      leave
  10:   c3                      ret
  11:   8d 76 00                lea    0x0(%esi),%esi

00000014 <main>:
  14:   55                      push   %ebp
  15:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  17:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  1a:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
  1d:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
  20:   6a 0b                   push   $0xb
  22:   6a 0a                   push   $0xa
  24:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   25 <main+0x11>
  29:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  2b:   c9                      leave
  2c:   c3                      ret
```

Ideally , listing (1) and (2) must be the same. But I see 
that there is movl, pushl etc in listing (1) whereas mov,push in 
lising (2). My question is:

1. Which is the correct assembly instruction actually executed on the processor?
2. In listing (1), I see this in the beginning:

```
.file "test.c"
    .globl accum
       .bss
       .align 4
       .type accum, @object
       .size accum, 4
    accum:
       .zero 4
       .text
       .p2align 2,,3
    .globl sum
       .type sum, @function
```

and this at end:

```
.size main, .-main
           .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
           .ident   "GCC: (GNU) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-9)"
```

What does this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The instruction is called `MOV` whatever variant is being used. The `l` suffix is just a gcc / AT&T assembly convention to specify the size of operands desired, in this case 4 byte operands.

In Intel syntax - where there is any ambiguity - instead of suffixing the instruction it is usual to tag the memory parameter with an indicator of the size required (e.g. `BYTE`, `WORD`, `DWORD`, etc.), it's just another way of achieving the same thing.

`89 55` is the correct sequence of bytes for `MOV` from the 32-bit register `EBP` to the 32-bit register `ESP`. There is nothing wrong in either listing.

---

Specifies the file that this assembly code was generated from:

```
.file "test.c"
```

Says that `accum` is a global symbol (C variable with external linkage):

```
    .globl accum
```

The following bytes should be placed in a `bss` section, this is a section that takes no space in the object file but is allocated and zeroed at runtime.

```
       .bss
```

Aligned on a 4 byte boundary:

```
       .align 4
```

It's an object (a variable, not some code):

```
       .type accum, @object
```

It's four bytes:

```
       .size accum, 4
```

Here is where `accum` is defined, four zero bytes.

```
    accum:
       .zero 4
```

Now switch from the `bss` section to the text section which is where functions are usually stored.

```
       .text
```

Add up to three bytes of padding to make sure we are on a 4 byte (2^2) boundary:

```
       .p2align 2,,3
```

`sum` is a global symbol and it's a function.

```
    .globl sum
       .type sum, @function
```

---

The size of `main` is "here" - "where `main` started":

```
.size main, .-main
```

These where gcc specific stack options are specified. Usually, this is where you choose to have an executable stack (not very safe) or not (usually preferred).

```
       .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Identify which version of the compiler generated this assembly:

```
       .ident   "GCC: (GNU) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-9)"
```

Comment: +9,000.  Thank you.  The bit about GCC specific stack options was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The assembler listing and the disassembler listing show the same code, but use a different syntax. The appended -l is the syntax variant used by gcc. That you have a different syntax in the tools (C-compiler output and disassembler) shows a weakness of your toolchain.

The disassemnbly at offset 11 in sum: shows just some garbage bytes. The entry point to the next function main is 4-byte aligned what gives this gap, fill with garbage.

The bunch of .statements are defined by the documentation of the assembler. Usually they dont give any executable code.